# Halt R script (run interactively) if a condition is not met

Tags: r, rstudio, data-analysis

Use case: I do interactive data analysis in RStudio, i.e. I highlight a bunch of code and hit run. Sometimes there are conditions that would statistically invalidate my analysis even though my code would still run fine. I want to stop the code or throw some very wild error in these cases.

Minimal working example:

```
stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)
x <- 42
```

If I highlight the two lines and run, `42` is still assigned to `x`. *That is bad* -- I don't want any line after `stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)` to run (since they are statistically invalid, while programmatically fine).  Is there a way to stop the code totally if the condition is not met?

Comment: Can you source() the script?

Comment: `source()` no longer allows me to work interactively (highlight code & run)

Comment: Sure but it does mean errors are picked up. You could source whenever you to check validity and run otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution is to wrap the code in brackets:

```
{
  stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)
  x <- 42
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nuclear option would be to terminate the session. This will either exit or restart Rstudio.

```
y <- 2
if (y ==2) quit(save="ask")
x <- 42
```

The `save="ask"` option brings up a prompt, and answering "no" will proceed to kill the session. Testing in Rstudio, the session terminates and restarts.

A better option would be to wrap your analysis in a function call with an exit strategy

```
doAnalysis <- function() {

   ...

   stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)

   ...


}
doAnalysis()
```

If you require intermittent variables to be produced during this function call, you can put them in the `Global` environment using

```
y <<- 2
```

Answer (score 1):

From `?options`:

```
options(error = utils::recover)

stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)
x <- 43
```

When run interactively, returns:

```
options(error = utils::recover)

stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)

Error: FALSE is not TRUE

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: stopifnot(TRUE, FALSE)

Selection: x <- 43
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection:
```

After hitting `0`:

```
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
No suitable frames for recover()
```

Note that this is a fairly drastic response (which you seem to desire). Further, the lines are still run, though without effect. This means it might be hard to locate the original error if you are running a lot of code. The best way to do this is to leave `options(error = NULL)` and to `source` your script.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like;

```
x <- 42
if (x == 42) stop("X is 42"); x <- 43
```

? The result will be x == 42 and you get an error

Comment: The result will be `x == 43`, as tested in Rstudio

Comment: For it looks like this: `> x <- 42` `> if (x==42) stop("x is 42"); x <- 43` `> x` `[1] 42`

Comment: apparently it only works if you add the `x <- 43` part to the end directly via semicolon. for whatever reason. I changed my answer to reflect this.